# Error in Java with FocusListener

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class LabelFrame extends JFrame {
    private final JTextField urlString; 
    private final JButton loadButton;
    String content;

public LabelFrame() { 
    super("WebStalker"); 
    setSize(600, 600);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    urlString = new JTextField("https:Search",30); 
    loadButton = new JButton("Load");


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("URL");
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(urlString);
    panel.add(loadButton);


    this.add(panel);
    pack(); 
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); 

    TextFieldHandler tHandler = new TextFieldHandler(); 
    ButtonHandler bHandler = new ButtonHandler();


    urlString.addActionListener(tHandler);
    loadButton.addActionListener(bHandler);

    urlString.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            urlString.setText("");
        }
    });


}
```

So this is the part of my code that i get an error. When i compile it i get this error :  is not abstract and does not override abstract method focusLost(FocusEvent) in FocusListener

I have no idea what's wrong. Could someone explain to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: override method focusLost within addFocusListener  as FocusListener have focusLost method as well that should be overriden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FocusListener` is a interface which declares two methods `focusGained` and `focusLost` but in your anonymous class implementation you only implemented `focusGained`. You simply need to implement `focusLost` too.

Alternatively you can derive from `java.awt.event.FocusAdapter`.

```
urlString.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() { ...
```

which has empty default implementations for `focusGained` and `focusLost` and therefore allows you to only specify the methods which are of interest to you.